# Calling the "history" command within a VIM shell script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, vim

Total programming newbie, probably extremely naive - bear with me.

As part of a current assignment, we've been given the task of grouping specific commands into a shell script. (date, hostname, arch...etc... top, history), using VIM to type the script.

My script is extremely basic, makes liberal use of "echo " to create blank lines for easy readability. I've got almost everything working - except every time I run the shell script, it fails when it reaches the "history" command.

The segment of the script is:

```
echo Finally, here is the output of the history command
echo
history
echo
echo -------------THE END---------------------
```

But upon running the script (using "sh [filename].sh"), the output reads:

```
[filename].sh: 66: [filename].sh: history: not found
```

I figure 66 refers to the line of the text document/script.

Can anyone help me get this working? I feel like it should be so simple, but I've tried numerous variations and am met with this "not found" message every time.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Thanks for your response!
I'm using a Virtual Machine to perform this task. Outside of VIM, the "history" command works fine, shows all of the past commands entered.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "a VIM shell script"? VIM is an editor, not a shell (although it has the ability to *run* shell commands). Do you just mean that you are using VIM to *write* a script? if so, that's largely irrelevant - which *shell* are you writing the script for, and how are you executing it?

Comment: Apologies - this is what I mean, I'm entirely new to this, I feel as though I don't know what I don't know!
I'm using VIM to write the script. The shell is "bash" (to the best of my understanding?). I'm running the script file by typing "sh shellattempt2.sh" (my file's name/extension) in the main terminal window, outside of VIM.

Typing "sh shellattempt2.sh" and hitting Enter outputs she script/text file with its correct formatting. Anywhere I've used a command  (date, etc) in the file, the command executes. But for "history", I get an error message; no history is printed.

Answer (score 1):

By typing `sh shellattempt2.sh`, you are likely forcing the script to be interpreted using the `/bin/sh` shell interpreter - which, on Ubuntu, is `dash` not bash by default

- [DashAsBinSh](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh)

The dash shell doesn't have `history` so that's why you are getting the error

```
[filename].sh: 66: [filename].sh: history: not found
```

Instead, make sure your script has an appropriate `shebang` as the first line

```
#!/bin/bash
```

then make it executable (`chmod +x [filename].sh`) and then run it using

```
./[filename].sh
```

---

HOWEVER, `bash` only enables history by default in *interactive shells*. The simplest way to access the shell history from a script (which runs in its own *non*-interactive shell) is probably to look directly at the history file itself, ex.

```
cat "$HISTFILE"
```

Comment: My typing "sh shellattempt2.sh" may be down to my inexperience - I'm quite sure I'm working with bash. Typing "echo $0" produces a "-bash" as output, so I think that means I'm working with the bash shell?

I've added the #!/bin/bash at the start of my script. Now, the error message is gone, but at the "history" section of the script, it seems to just skip it. So I'm inclined to think, whatever "history" is being called, is blank?

(when I substituted "history" with "cat $HISTFILE", the script seemed to break at that point).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to steeldriver's answer, to output history of current bash session in case if you've added `#!/bin/bash`, you could use `source` function:

```
source shellattempt2.sh
```

Because of with `#!/bin/bash` added there's no history output in current bash session.

If you replace `history` by `cat $HISTFILE` or `cat "$HISTFILE"` also use `source`. But it outputs not current bash session's history.

```
source --help
source: source filename [arguments]
    Execute commands from a file in the current shell.

    Read and execute commands from FILENAME in the current shell.  The
    entries in $PATH are used to find the directory containing FILENAME.
    If any ARGUMENTS are supplied, they become the positional parameters
    when FILENAME is executed.

    Exit Status:
    Returns the status of the last command executed in FILENAME; fails if
    FILENAME cannot be read.
```

Comment: Okay - by following what you said, my script worked as I intended it to. Thanks!